# MySQL duplicate large text saving

Tags: mysql

I'd like to send message to multiple user using MySQL at my game server.
On this procedure, multiple duplicate string(MediumText, 100~500 chars) data will be saved in a same column.

100k user is expected to receive mail.

example(in CSV) :

```
ID,Item,Content,(SentDate,Expdate)
123148223598230,"{Crystal:100}","Sorry for the inconvenience...blahblah"
133124124515435,"{Crystal:100}","Sorry for the inconvenience...blahblah"
348209385093285,"{Crystal:100}","Sorry for the inconvenience...blahblah"
209580293509233,"{Crystal:100}","Sorry for the inconvenience...blahblah"
...
```

1.. The concern is, is MySQL smart enough to detect this duplicate values and store the data 'efficiently', storing duplicate values only once?

2.a. If so, How do I make MySQL do the trick?(Or, does it automatically does the trick?)

2.b. If not, what breakthrough would you recommend?

New table for the text values? Or just store the data on db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will not automatically detect that you have duplicate text in the comments column.  If you expect to have large duplication across comments, you can try normalizing your data by creating a new table which solely contains comments.  Then, in your current table, replace the comment with a foreign key pointing to this new table.

MySQL's `ENUM` type might also be something to consider here, but if there are many unique comments, using a bona fide separate table would probably be cleaner.